# How to include a dll file to project's deployment in JDeveloper IDE

Tags: java, packaging, jdeveloper

I'm building a face recognition app and i have to include the `opencv_java411.dll` to my project.

Regarding the coding, i'm loading some libraries from that **dll** as follows:

```java
  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

This is the directory where I've put my **dll** file

[image]

When i'm trying to deploy it though, it does not appear in the output list

[image]

And as expected, the **deployed**`jar` file does not include it

---

How can i include it properly?

Comment: Are there any updates on this question? Did you find a solution?